# Apache server is not able to access from other system

Tags: php, apache

I have a static Ip address. I configured all my projects in my apache server. And i put my apache server in online mode i'm not able to access my projects from other system. I'm using wamp apache server version 2.2.8. and windows 7 os. How can i able to access my projects from other system??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you've configured your Apache that it just is accessible from the local machine or something else is preventing the access (i.e. Windows firewall, networking and such).

My advice:

- Try checking your Windows firewall if its configured to let http pass to your apache.
- Try checking your httpd.conf if you don't listen to just a certain host.
- Try checking if your remote machine has any networking issues with prevents it to reach your apache.

This is how the `httpd.conf` might look like:

```
/* Example 1: Access only from local machine */
Listen 127.0.0.1:80

/* Example 2: Access from every machine */
Listen 80
```

Comment: Think is one more machine also have the same configuration it's working perfectly with one more static IP. But my machine only not able to access from outside. And there is no issues on the httpd.conf file.

Comment: Yes problem with my windows firewall. Once i turned off it's working perfectly. Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured your router correctly and configured the Windows firewall?